# Find square numbers in product

Tags: functions, function-construction

If I have the product of some unique numbers such as:

$9   . 6   . 8 . 10  = 4320$

(edit where each of the products must be less than or equal to a given number, 10)

If I want to find if any of the numbers is a square I would decompose as follows:

$(3\,.\,3)\,.\,(3\,.\,2)\,.\,(4\,.\,2)\,.\,(5\,\,.\,2) = 4320$

here obviously 9 is the square number but is there a function to do that in Mathematica 9?

The nearest I have found finds powers of unique primes:

$2^5 . 3^3 . 5       = 4320$

using the function:

```
FactorInteger[4320]
{{2, 5}, {3, 3}, {5, 1}}
```

Is there any general way to find if a number such as 4320 contains any square numbers in products such as 9 such that this is less than or equal to 10 and is still a product of 4 numbers in this case?

Comment: Does `SquareFreeQ` work for you?

Comment: There are more squares in $4320$ beyond $9$: you also have $4=2^2$, $16=4^2$. Do you want a list of all primes squared, or also non-primes?

Comment: SquareFreeQ pulls all the squares I need just the squares present in the 4 unique numbers that make the product and yes I mean prime squares only.

Comment: I begin to see this might be impossible!

Comment: `First[#]^2 & /@ Select[FactorInteger[4320], #[[2]] > 1 &]` ?

Comment: How about `PrimePowerQ`?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  I think I have failed to point out that the product is composed of numbers that must be less than a a given number in this case 10. That means perhaps that piece of code could be incorporated into a function that first tests 4 and then 9 to see if 4320 can be reconstructed with just four numbers again sorting which possibility works so for '4' it would fail 4.27.5.8 there is a number > 10 whilst 9. 5.6.8 works.

Comment: @Carl Woll  had missed some information in the original question so PrimePowerQ would not do. It looks like what I'm asking is an iterative process afterall unless I'm wrong because there is no way as far as I can see to find the answer without some kind of trial process.

Comment: The issue is to find the unique decomposition (maybe that was obvious, but I note it because the wording of the question seems to go in a different direction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had an idea based on @AccidentalFourierTransform comment.

```
First[#]^2 & /@ Select[FactorInteger[4320], #[[2]] > 1 &]
```

produces two squares in the case of 4320 '4' and '9' but only one will reconstruct 4320 with just 4 numbers less than or equal to 10.

4 would fail since since 4 is less than half of 10 therefore all squares less than 5 can be excluded since 10.9.8.4 < 4320.

```
Select[First[#]^2 & /@ Select[FactorInteger[4320], #[[2]] > 1 &], 5<= # <= 10 &]
```

and generalised replacing constants shown as convenient:

```
Select[First[#]^2 & /@ Select[FactorInteger[m], #[[2]] > 1 &], (n/2) <= # <= n &]
```